# Bootstrap Carousel Previous Functionality

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel to create a multiple item slider like is found [here.](http://bootply.com/94444)

Everything works fine so long as you are going in the 'Next' direction. The issue I am having is when you click the 'previous' button, it throws 3 images backwards to get you to the 'previous' slide.

I am not sure if it is a bootstrap hack, or what is causing it to function improperly, but it won't work as is for my current needs. What do I need to do to get it to only slide back 1 item?

You can see in the *bootply* example, if you click the 'previous' button, it does this weird effect, but I would like it to only go back one item, just like it does when it progresses by clicking the 'next' button.

Answer (score 0):

In codepen at least the effect is consistent http://codepen.io/Kebten/pen/ZGpLYx ;-)

```
if ("A little bit of code to keep the folks at S.O. happy") {
    var message = "this code can be ignored";
}
```